# Interact with my app with GUI _and_ CLI, at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I have a PyQt desktop application with interactive GUI.

Basically it is an instrument controller: clicking on buttons may start a pump, trigger a sound alarm, some threads continuously read data from flowmeter, etc.

I want to be able to control the app/instrument remotely.

The instrument and the computer running the Qt desktop app is in a remote site with a (very) slow  and costly Internet connection, so TeamViewer-like solution is not acceptable ; however I can connect to the linux computer in SSH.

That is why I though it could be a decent solution to interact with my app using a command-line interface.

I know it is possible to do an app which is launched either as desktop GUI or as CLI, but is it possible to interact with a CLI on an already-running desktop GUI?

I want the desktop to be running all the time, it should never stop.
I want that when I start the pump with the CLI, it appears as "started" in the GUI as well at the same time.

Said in other words, I would like to be able to write some CLI's commands that act like if I virtually click on GUI's button.

Comment: The Python application could start a thread that reads input from `stdin` or from some port. Is this an option for you?

Comment: Hi! This sounds like a really good solution for the problem. If the application logic is well separated from the GUI, you can take advantage of that encapsulation (Check out Model-view-controller patterns). If the code is structured like that, you should be able to write many separate front ends (GUI or CLI). After that, you'd just need to account for race conditions between multiple connected front ends.

Comment: @pschill: that would be a good quick and easy solution. eyllanesc's solution is more "Qt-integrated" but yours requires less changes in my already-existing code. I have to think about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases it is better to have a service that always runs and that the GUI and CLI are clients:

```
      ┌-----------------  GUI     
      ↓
┌----------┐
| Service  | ←----------  CLI
└----------┘
      ↑
      └-----------------  Another Client
```

The communication between the clients must be done by some Inter process communication (IPC) like DBus, ZeroMQ, Mqtt, etc. In the case of Qt you could use 
[Qt Remote Objects (QtRO)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html).

So the GUI, CLI or any client would make requests to the service to modify any output (start a pump, trigger a sound alarm, etc) and receive notifications.

---

In the following example it illustrates what I indicated in the previous lines.

To do this, first start the service.py and then cli.py or gui.py, in the case of the GUI with the button the status of the "bumb" that is displayed with a QLabel is changed. In the case of the cli you must place "on" or "off" to change the status of the "bumb".

**service.py**

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtRemoteObjects


class Bumb(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._current_state = False

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def pushCurrentState(self, state):
        pass

    def _get_current_state(self):
        return self._current_state

    def _set_current_state(self, state):
        if self._current_state != state:
            self._current_state = state
            print("current state:", state)
            self.currentStateChanged.emit(state)

    currentStateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    currentState = QtCore.pyqtProperty(
        bool,
        fget=_get_current_state,
        fset=_set_current_state,
        notify=currentStateChanged,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    bumb = Bumb()

    register_node = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectRegistryHost(
        QtCore.QUrl("local:registry")
    )
    source_node = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectHost(
        QtCore.QUrl("local:replica"), QtCore.QUrl("local:registry")
    )
    source_node.enableRemoting(bumb, "bumb")

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**gui.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtRemoteObjects


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, bumb, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._bumb = bumb

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Change State")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(text="Bumb", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    @property
    def bumb(self):
        return self._bumb

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onClicked(self):
        self.bumb.setProperty("currentState", not self.bumb.property("currentState"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def initConnection(self):
        self.bumb.currentStateChanged.connect(self.onCurrentStateChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def onCurrentStateChanged(self, state):
        color = QtGui.QColor("red") if state else QtGui.QColor("green")
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: {}".format(color.name()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    replica_node = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectNode(QtCore.QUrl("local:registry"))
    replica_bumb = replica_node.acquireDynamic("bumb")

    w = Widget(replica_bumb)
    w.show()

    replica_bumb.initialized.connect(w.initConnection)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**cli.py**

```py
import platform
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtRemoteObjects


class NativeMessenger(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_qin = QtCore.QFile()

        self.m_qin.open(
            sys.stdin.fileno(), QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly | QtCore.QIODevice.Unbuffered
        )

        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            import win32api

            if sys.platform == "win32":
                import os
                import msvcrt

                if platform.python_implementation() == "PyPy":
                    os.fdopen(fh.fileno(), "wb", 0)
                else:
                    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

            self.m_notifier = QtCore.QWinEventNotifier(
                win32api.GetStdHandle(win32api.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
            )

        else:
            self.m_notifier = QtCore.QSocketNotifier(
                sys.stdin.fileno(), QtCore.QSocketNotifier.Read, self
            )

        self.m_notifier.activated.connect(self.readyRead)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def readyRead(self):
        line = self.m_qin.readLine().data().decode().strip()
        self.messageChanged.emit(line)


class Manager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, bumb, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._bumb = bumb

    @property
    def bumb(self):
        return self._bumb

    def execute(self, command):
        commands = {"on": True, "off": False}
        state = commands.get(command)
        if state is not None:
            self.bumb.setProperty("currentState", state)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def initConnection(self):
        self.bumb.currentStateChanged.connect(self.onCurrentStateChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def onCurrentStateChanged(self, state):
        print("LOG:", state)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    replica_node = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectNode(QtCore.QUrl("local:registry"))
    replica_bumb = replica_node.acquireDynamic("bumb")

    manager = Manager(replica_bumb)

    replica_bumb.initialized.connect(manager.initConnection)

    messenger = NativeMessenger()
    messenger.messageChanged.connect(manager.execute)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Qt Remote Objects (QtRO) sounds interresting, I didn't know about it. Thanks for the detailled example!